# Distance from a point to a plane in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

How can we calculate the distance from a point to a plane
in normed spaces ? where we are not inner product, for example:

Calculate the distance in $(C[0,1],||\cdot||)$ endowed with the supremum norm $$||f||=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$$ from the function $f(t)=t^2$ to the linear hull of the functions $g(t)=t$  and  $h(t)=\sin(t)$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $\inf\{\,\lVert f-(ag+bh)\rVert:a,b\in\mathbb R\,\}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is a particular method to calculate ?

Comment: There is no general method; this is why curve fitting is usually done with least squares (for which we can use inner product structure). Two observations: (i) the minimum is attained, by compactness. Uniqueness probably holds, but is not obvious. (ii) Letting $r=f-(ag+bh)$ be the remainder, we can say that $\max r=\max(-r)$ at the optimal value of $a,b$. Otherwise we could either add or subtract a multiple of $t$ (positive function) to decrease one without increasing the other.

Comment: Here's an idea. We are looking for $b$ such that $t^2-b\sin t$ most closely resembles a line. Thus, we want to minimize the amount of convexity in this function. The second derivative is $2+b\sin t$. If we choose $b=-2/(1-\cos 1)$, this integrates to zero. Then you find the best fitting line to $t^2+2(1-\cos 1)\sin t$, which appears to be $y\approx 4.666 t$. The distance is less than $0.029$. ... However, if this is an exercise meant to be solved exactly, not approximately on a computer, then I've no idea.

Comment: I'm still curious about this one. Did you give $t^2$, $t$ and $\sin t$ just as a random example, or is this a problem in which you are expected to give the exact value of distance?